# Does cakephp implicitly implement on delete cascade for BTM association

Tags: cakephp

I am a beginner with cakephp and I am trying to understand it through the bookmarker app tutorial.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html

So here is the SQL scheme :

```
    CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE bookmarks (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    description TEXT,
    url TEXT,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY user_key (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME,
    UNIQUE KEY (title)
);

CREATE TABLE bookmarks_tags (
    bookmark_id INT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (bookmark_id, tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY tag_key(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id),
    FOREIGN KEY bookmark_key(bookmark_id) REFERENCES bookmarks(id)
);
```

So here is what I did after "bake all" ->

- I went and added a user in my app and added a bookmark and tag for the user.
- Now I am trying to delete the user which throws a SQL Error saying it violates foreign key constraint as bookmarks refer to a user. Makes sense.
- The problem is here - I can go and delete a bookmark without any error, however in my opinion it should throw an error because bookmarks_tags refers to a bookmark and that too violates referential integrity.

So can someone please tell me how this is working internally. It is my first time with CakePHP and MVC in general and I am trying to understand the internal workings of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by default CakePHP removes related record from the join table first if the primary record is deleted. It's done so because in most case you don't care about association if primary record itself is deleted.

You can prevent automatic removal of join table records by setting `dependent` option to `false` in association config as stated [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations).

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.